# Create a random string each time a model object is saved to database

Tags: django, django-models

In my models.py, I have:

```
def MakeOTP():
    import random,string
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=4))


class Prescriptionshare(models.Model):
    prid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    checkin =models.ForeignKey(Checkins, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=MakeOTP())
```

In my django shell, I've tried the following:

```
pq = Prescriptionshare(customer = cus, checkin = chk)
pq.save()
```

The problem is that each time this is executed, I get the same string in otp field. There is no random change of string.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Assuming the OTP is used for security, you **must not** use the random module. The Mersenne Twister algorithm is completely insecure for cryptographic purposes, with a relatively small sample of outputs, anyone can recover the internal state and predict future outputs. Use the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) or `django.utils.crypto.get_random_string()` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the **`()`** from **`default=MakeOTP()`**

```
class Prescriptionshare(models.Model):
    # your code
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=MakeOTP) # here, remove the "()"
```

**After making changes in the models, you should migrate the DB**

---

**Why this happening?**
If you use **`MakeOTP()`**, Django takes the output of the function, where as if you use **`MakeOTP`** (without parenthesis) Django consider it as ***callable function***.
That is,  when paranthesis used, method is called once the migrations are run and its value is ***used as the default value*** and when paranthesis are not used, ***function reference called everytime while object creation***.

Comment: To clarify the situation here, when paranthesis used, method is called once the migrations are run and its value is used as the default value, you need to pass it as a function reference for it to be called everytime

Comment: @OzgurAkcali Thanks for your tip :)